# Получить текущее время пользователя через telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telebot, бот, дата, datetime

Я пишу бот (telebot) для просмотра анонсов мероприятий некоторой организации. Есть БД, которая содержит в таблице следующие поля: id мероприятия, описание мероприятия, а также его дату и время.

Необходимо, чтобы пользователь, который начинает пользоваться ботом, сразу же получал в ответ актуальные мероприятия, информация о которых хранится в БД. Для этого мне необходимо узнать текущее время пользователя и сравнить с временем мероприятия, выдав только те мероприятия, которые запланированы в будущем.

````
``` @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
    tconv = lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y", time.localtime(x))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, tconv(message.date))``
````

Последняя строка нужна для проверки, но она выводит код в формате: "22:41:27 14.12.2023" **Как сделать так, чтобы мы получали количество секунд с 1 января 1970?** Мне кажется, так просто легче будет сравнивать с датой из БД. С другой стороны, дату в БД тоже вводить нужно в формате: год, месяц, день, час, минуты, а значит конвертировать в секунды. Может быть, нужно тогда как-то спроектировать БД иначе? Чтобы было удобнее? Выслушаю все варианты. Прошу не ругать, если глупый вопрос, я только учусь :(

Answer (score 0):

```
user_date = message.date
```

Все просто!